# Avoid heroku to try to clone my project's submodule

Tags: git, heroku, bitbucket, git-submodules, heroku-toolbelt

When deploying my app to heroku it is trying and failing to clone a (private) git submodule that is useful for development but not for deployment.

I do not want to hardcode my bitbucket credentials on the submodule config.

Is there any way to tell heroku to ignore the submodule.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Heroku's tech support answer:

> Hi Pedro,
>
> git itself doesn't have a way of ignoring submodules on push, my only
>   idea would be to de-initialize and re-initialize during each push,
>   perhaps automating this via git's pre-push hook. However, doing this
>   would delete and re-clone the repository each time, which is very
>   inefficient.
>
> Is this private repository a utility that you've developed on your
>   own? Or is it a version of some other software that you maintain a
>   copy of? Can the package be installed/loaded into your development
>   environment in a way other than the git submodule method?
>
> Thanks! Jason